# Copy Hyperlink to Clipboard not working in lightning page

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

We have a copy button that allows the user to copy a piece of specific information to the clipboard and piece of that information is a hyperlink. Here's the sample piece of code:

```
const container = this.template.querySelector(".copyContainer");
const range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(container);
const selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
const successful = document.execCommand('copy');
```

**Note:** I tried the code in the salesforce playground and LWC local development and is working as expected. However, when we try it inside the salesforce org, it's getting an error:

> Failed to execute 'addRange' on 'Selection': parameter 1 is not of type 'Range'.

Any solutions or suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate, along with some source code?

Comment: Hello @arut, see [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/M-YA1lFDU/1/edit) to see working code. On the click of a button, it will copy the hyperlink to the clipboard. But when I try to deploy it in the salesforce org, it's malfunctioning and throwing an error.

Comment: Take a look at Playground limitations section here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.install_playground & the important note section at the bottom in this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work. When you are running your code in playground, I don't think Lightning Locker is acting on your code. So, that's possibly the reason why your code is working in playground.

Comment: Besides, Salesforce doesn't recommend using document and window elements. So, when you run code in org, the lightning framework and lightning locker are possibly stripping out certain required attributes on the range object or even encapsulating the range object itself.

If you simply want the hyperlink or text value, you could use either `this.template.querySelector('.container').firstChild["href"]` or `this.template.querySelector('.container').textContent`. 

Not sure about your reason behind choosing to use the window and document methods.

Answer (score 0):

Look like now `document.execCommand('copy');` is deprecated and `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` is not allowed by Lightning Security Locker, which means in 2023 there is no way to implement this functionality inside LWC.